# Inserting br into a textnode

Tags: javascript, append, textnode

This might seem odd. I have a div with the id of 'quotes', and inside there is a blockquote. I thought it would be interesting to add line breaks, if the quoted text were poetry, and I thought you could use a '@' as a conditional line break, and then replace this with the br element as follows:

```
function addBr() {
    var c = document.getElementById("quotes");
    var t = c.getElementsByTagName("blockquote");    
    var reg = new RegExp("@", "g");
    for (var i = 0; i < t.length; i++) {
        var r = t[i].lastChild.nodeValue.match(reg);
        if (r !== null) {
            var text = t[i].childNodes[0];
            var q = t[i].lastChild.nodeValue.indexOf("@");
            var x = document.createElement("br");
            t[i].insertBefore(x, text.splitText(q));
            t[i].lastChild.nodeValue = t[i].lastChild.nodeValue.replace(/\@/g, "");
        }
    }
}
```

This works, but only for the first instance, so I need a loop, but I can't figure that out.
The div would be like this:

```
<div id = 'quotes'>
<blockquote> Some line, @ Some line, @ Some line@ </blockquote>
</div>
```

Any hints would be deeply appreciated.

Comment: Why note just use `\n` (newline)? It's valid for formatting strings (which text nodes are, anyways).

Comment: @Matt: Because new lines within text nodes are not rendered as line breaks by browsers.

Answer (score 1):

Start with the last match of `@` within the text node and work backwards. The following function does this and also has the benefit of eliminating the unnecessary regex, uses clearer variable names and is shorter:

```
function addBr() {
    var c = document.getElementById("quotes");
    var t = c.getElementsByTagName("blockquote");
    for (var i = 0; i < t.length; i++) {
        var splitPos, textNode = t[i].lastChild;

        while ( (splitPos = textNode.data.lastIndexOf("@")) != -1 ) {
            var newTextNode = textNode.splitText(splitPos);

            // Remove the @ from the start of the new text node
            newTextNode.deleteData(0, 1);

            var br = document.createElement("br");
            t[i].insertBefore(br, newTextNode);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest simply doing this:

```
function addBr() {
    var c = document.getElementById("quotes");
    var t = c.getElementsByTagName("blockquote");    
    for (var i = 0; i < t.length; i++)
        r.innerHTML = r.innerHTML.replace(/@/g, "<br />");
}
```

What is a "conditional line break"? I don't see anything in your code that decides when to break the line...

Comment: Maybe it's the special "magic" hyphen that only breaks when the browser has to - `&shy;` or `&#8203;` I think